# Android Interface Webview

Tags: android, xml, interface, webview

I want to create an interface for my android project. I have 4 seperate projects which will be used as libraries for the final project, 3 of which contain webviews. On the startup screen I want to have 4 buttons and then maybe use the onClick function to launch the respective app. I am having problems declaring the webview in my xml though. The libraries when imported contain webviews so where should they go in the xml? Also is there a way to start the activity of the project when the button is clicked? Instead of just calling methods from the project?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What I do in this case is to extend the Service/Activity class from the other project in the project where I want to use it and then add it to the manifest.
For the layout files I was not able to use them directly in another project. So you could add an abstract Method to your webview activitys like

`protected int getLayoutId()`

and then copy your XML layout files to the core project where you reference the layouts using that method. Don't know if there is any better way to solve this I wasnt able to find any other solution.

Comment: Do you have any sample code for this? Finding it a bit confusing! Thanks

Comment: I got this working in the end but thanks for your help! Do I just delete the question now?

Comment: hey sorry I've been busy these days. With which solution did you come up in the end? I'm facing these kind of problems also often so I'm interested if you found any better solution. I've created my example at http://app-solut.com/2011/04/using-android-activities-and-services-in-multiple-projects/